# How to disable alert when push notification is received and app is opened?

Tags: ios, push-notification

When my app is opened and it receives push notification alert is shown.

I want to remove it. I tried to remove key `alert` in payload, but then all notifications including one when the app is closed are gone.

How can I disable alert only and prevent it from appearing ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more with code?

Comment: when app is in foreground, and push notification is received , no banner appears, how are you getting alert? Have you write any code for showing  Alert in your didReceiveRemoteNotification?

Comment: @RenukaCE Which code in particular are you interested in ?

Comment: @Muneeba I dont have any code for showing alert. Only Parse's PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out the line

```
PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
```

in your `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method. Parse api is showing that alert.

[Check this link for details](https://www.parse.com/questions/pfpush-handlepush)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in your `AppDelegate.m` where you have configured the delegate of receiving push notification like below

```
-(void)onReceivePushNotification:(NSDictionary *) pushDict andPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload {
[payload valueForKey:@"title"];
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert !" message:[pushDict valueForKey:@"alert"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil ,nil];
[message setTag:kAlertViewPushNotification];
if([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateInActive)
   [message show];
}
```

Or `UIAlertController` if you are using `iOS 8.0 or Later`

Comment: This is code for showing alert ? I need opposite - hiding the existing one.

Comment: means if there is already an alert, Hide it and show the received one?